# PostgreSQL 10: With this upsert function, how to update only if column value is different?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm looking to update `apr` only if it's different, right now, it looks like it updates regardless if it's different or same:

```
   INSERT INTO live_mytable (id, loan_type, apr, term, oldestyear) 
   SELECT id, loan_type, apr, term, oldestyear
   FROM   imp_mytable 
   ON CONFLICT (id,loan_type,term,oldestyear) DO update
   set apr = excluded.apr;
```

How can this query be changed to only update if value is different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `WHERE` clause on the update:

```
 INSERT INTO live_mytable (id, loan_type, apr, term, oldestyear) 
   SELECT id, loan_type, apr, term, oldestyear
   FROM   imp_mytable 
 ON CONFLICT (id,loan_type,term,oldestyear) 
 DO update
   set apr = excluded.apr
 WHERE 
      live_mytable.apr IS DISTINCT FROM 
      EXCLUDED.apr;
```