# PostgreSQL 10: How to delete orphan rows in Table A on only IDs existing in Table B?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

How do I delete orphan rows in `Table A` * *denotes orphan row*:

```
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| ID      | option | category | rates | Table A
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| a       | f      | null     | 2.5   |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| a       | f      | d        | 2     |*
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| a       | g      | e        | 3     |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| c       | g      | e        | 4     |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| d       | f      | d        | 1     |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
```

On only IDs existing in `Table B` (only check IDs `a` & `c`, leave `d` alone):

```
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| ID      | option | category | rates | Table B
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| a       | f      | null     | 2.5   |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| a       | g      | e        | 3     |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| c       | g      | e        | 4     |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
```

Result(only the second row `a,f,d,2` was deleted):

```
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| ID      | option | category | rates | Table A
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| a       | f      | null     | 2.5   |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| a       | g      | e        | 3     |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| c       | g      | e        | 4     |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
| d       | f      | d        | 1     |
+---------+--------+----------+-------+
```

This is just an example, real tables contain many more IDs and variations.

My thinking is that I should `group by ID` on `Table B` to a temp table then `loop` delete on non matching rows on `Table A` per ID.

Because I'm new to PostgreSQL, can you show me how this can be done? I've searched on loop deletes, but not sure how to pass the ID from temp table to the loop. Also, if there's a better way, please let me know as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want this:

```
DELETE from tableA
 USING tableB
 WHERE 
   -- ignore rows with IDs that don't exist in tableB
   tableA.ID = tableB.ID
   -- ignore rows that have an exact all-column match in tableB
   AND NOT EXISTS (select * from tableB where tableB.* is not distinct from tableA.*);
```

`is not distinct from` is a bit like "equals" (the `=` operator) except that it's also true when compared columns are both NULL, whereas `row(x,null) = row(x,null)` is null, not true. This is relevant at least for your `category` column, that is nullable in the sample data.

Comment: For `AND NOT EXISTS (select * from tableB where tableB.* is not distinct from tableA.*);` what if I'm not looking for it to match all columns but leave the column `rates` out? I'm assuming `AND NOT EXISTS (select * from tableB where tableB.ID <> tableA.ID OR tableB.option <> tableA.option OR tableB.category <> tableA.category );`?

Comment: or would this work? `AND NOT EXISTS (select * from tableB where tableB.ID is not distinct from tableA.ID AND tableB.option is not distinct from tableA.option AND tableB.category is not distinct from tableA.category );`

Comment: @sojim2: your second form looks good. Remember that `is not distinct from` is a double negation. Use `=` to simplify for the columns that you know cannot be NULL (tableA.id=tableB.id for instance)

Comment: Got it, so this would work if tableB has nulls and tableA has `'-1'` in place of those nulls (assuming all `varchar` fields):
`AND NOT EXISTS (select * from tableB where COALESCE(tableB.ID,'-1')=tableA.ID AND COALESCE(tableB.option,'-1')=tableA.option AND COALESCE(tableB.category,'-1')=tableA.category );`

Comment: The next question may lead to then why do I have `-1` in place of nulls? It's because of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932543/postgresql-10-with-this-upsert-function-how-to-update-only-if-column-value-is (the upsert function doesn't recognize `null` fields so I have to set `-1` in place of `nulls`, it makes me wonder though if we can use `is not distinct from` somehow in that function because it feels `-1` in place of `nulls` is a bit hacky and will lead to other workarounds in the future.

Comment: Looks like `coalesce` isn't recommended because it's non-SARGable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828329/why-use-is-distinct-from-postgres

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from A using (
select distinct A.* from A, B where A.ID = B.ID   --- all A that have same ID with B
except 
select * from B 
) x   ---- this one has all A rows without B rows only where A.id = B.id
where --- now the join
   A.ID = x.ID and
   A.option = x.option and
   A.category = X.category and
   A.rates = X.rates
```

Would be better to have a clear PK  , ID is misleading , usually an ID is unique

Comment: This table has primary key on multiple fields unfortunately. You're right, ID is misleading, I have it as company on the actual table. Will keep this in mind on future questions. I'll test this out and confirm answer once completed.